# pdf report view inside browser

Tags: pdf, browser, content-disposition

I have created this report using BIRT and phpjavabridge

```
<?php

header("Content-type: application/pdf");
header("Content-Disposition: inline; filename=downloaded.pdf");

require_once("http://127.0.0.1:8080/JavaBridge/java/Java.inc");
header("Content-type: text/html");



// the report file to render
$myReport = "test.rptdesign";

// load resources, .rpt files and images from the current working dir
$here = getcwd();

$ctx = java_context()->getServletContext();
$birtReportEngine =        java("org.eclipse.birt.php.birtengine.BirtEngine")->getBirtEngine($ctx);
java_context()->onShutdown(java("org.eclipse.birt.php.birtengine.BirtEngine")->getShutdownHook());


// Create a HTML render context

try{

// Load the report design
$design = $birtReportEngine->openReportDesign("${here}/${myReport}");
$task = $birtReportEngine->createRunAndRenderTask( $design );
$task->setParameterValue("sample", new java("java.lang.String", "Hello world!"));

// Add HTML render options
$options = new java("org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.PDFRenderOption");
$options->setOutputFormat($options->OUTPUT_FORMAT_PDF);

// Create the output
$out = new java("java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream");
$options->setOutputStream($out);
$task->setRenderOption($options);
$task->run ();
$task->close();

} catch (JavaException $e) {
    echo $e; //"Error Calling BIRT";

}


// Return the generated output to the client
echo java_values($out->toByteArray());


?>
```

The report viewed perfectly inside Internet Explorer 8.0 as it triggered the Adobe Acrobat plugin. The problem is when I opened the report inside Mozilla Firefox 3.5.4 and Google Chrome 4.0.233 it showed me the binary string content of the pdf file, instead of triggering the Adobe Acrobat plugin.

I have checked this by putting a pdf file in the htdoc folder and call it from Firefox and Chrome, it worked just fine. But why the header wont work for the report?

*Also why the header only work for IE 8.0? I need the report to be viewed in all major browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Content-type should be  "application/pdf"

(or "application/x-pdf", for more recent pdf formats)

I think that if you change

```
header("Content-type: text/html");
to
header("Content-type: application/pdf");
```

in the code above, the browsers mentioned should start rendering the pdf documents properly (provided they are so configured), and IE will continue working ok (IE has some [**Automatic MIME Type Detection**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms775147(VS.85).aspx) (based on the first few hundred bytes of content), which is a mixed blessing...)

Comment: ahh my bad I was too quickly blame it on the browser. Thank you